# Why does pyright raise a warning message whenever I try to change a value in a list?

Tags: python, pyright

I have the code:

```
listA = [1,2,3]
listA[0] = 'A'
```

Which works, but pyright raises the warning

```
argument of type 'Literal['A']' cannot be assigned to parameter '__value' of type 'int' in function '__setitem__'
'Literal['A']' is incompatible with 'int'
```

This is the only code being run and it executes as intended but the warning is incredibly annoying. Anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: Because it's assumed that, given all values initially in the list are integers, all values _ever_ in the list should be integers. `'A'` isn't an integer -> `'Literal['A']' is incompatible with 'int'`. If you intend a wider type than is inferred, be explicit.

Comment: Also, if you don't find this particular warning useful for your needs, you can disable it.

Comment: To put it more bluntly, the tool is complaining because that sort of thing is almost always a mistake. "This is the only code being run and it executes as intended" yeah, maybe *right now* that's true, but code changes over time. What happens when somebody (possibly including you 6 months from now) sees a literal list of ints and writes something like `list_squares = [x ** 2 for x in listA]`, not realizing somebody changed one of them to a string?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that seems to be it, but if I use the string method .splitlines() to form the list it throws a similar warning despite both items being strings

Comment: `Literal['A']` _is_ compatible with `str`, so that would surprise me.

Comment: what i got this from is `ListA = 'test1\ntest2\ntest3'`  `ListB = ['a','b']`  `ListA = ListA.splitlines()`  `ListA[0] = ''.join(ListB)`

Comment: ...and what was the result? [Edit] the question.

Answer (score 1):

When a type checker sees the code

```
listA = [1, 2, 3]
```

it attempts to (immediately) infer what the intended type of `listA` is. In this case, the right-hand side is a `list[int]`, so your type check with make a note that `listA` is a `list[int]`.

When you later write

```
listA[0] = 'A'
```

your type checker will complain since you're attempting to assign a string (a `Literal['A']`)  to a target of type `int`. That's exactly the kind of mistake that type checkers are designed to check for and prevent.

Presumably, you don't actually want `listA` to be a `list[int]`. To fix this, you can just [annotate it explicitly with the correct type](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/). For example:

```
listA: list[int | str] = [1, 2, 3]
```